# how to disable Creating tcp connection to ('redis', 6379) print?

Tags: redis, django-channels

I have integrated django channel and redis server in my django application but i am running my django application i am keep on getting below print

> aioredis[38]                connection|    DEBUG| Creating tcp connection to ('redis', 6379)

Can somebody help me how to disable aioredis's connection debug print or what could be the reason i am getting this print . Please note client ws is successfully connected to django server's ws connection

Below version of channels and channels_redis i am using

> channels~=2.0,>=2.0.2
> channels_redis~=2.0

I have hosted the redis server on port no 6379 from docker-compose yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  redis:
  image: redis:latest
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
   - redis
```

Logger setting in project

```
LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG"
        LOGGING = {
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': True,
            'formatters': {
                'verbose': {
                    '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
                    'format':'%(asctime)s %(name)s[%(process)d] %(module)25s| %(log_color)s%(levelname)8s| %(message)s',
                    'datefmt':'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
            },
            'simple': {
            '   format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console':{
                'level': LOG_LEVEL,
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
        },
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            },
            '': {
                'level': LOG_LEVEL,
                'handlers': ['console'],
            },
            'gunicorn.access': {
                'handlers': ['console']
            },
            'gunicorn.error': {
                'handlers': ['console']
            }
            
        }
        }
```

Comment: Which server are you using and how do you run the server? You should be able to change the log level in the run server command

Comment: Also post your LOGGING configuration from settings.py if you have one

Comment: updated logging config

Comment: Great! Can you see the issue now? You defined the log level to be debug(the most verbose level) and you're getting debug and all other messages. By default, the log level is usually INFO so you don't get debug messages like the one you posted. So, if you don't want to see message, either change the log level as you have it now or specifically for aioredis

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the root cause, could you please tell me how to specifically disable DEBUG log leve for aioredis module?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the list of loggers in your logging configuration

```
'aioredis': {
    'level': 'INFO',
    'handlers': ['console'],
},
```